# java regular Expression for splitting a string

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string like below, want to split it based on a condition.

```
|RECEIVE|Low| eventId=139569 msg=W4N Alert :: Critical : Interface Utilization for GigabitEthernet0/1 90.0 % in=2442 out=0 categorySignificance=/Normal categoryBehavior=/Communicate/Query categoryDeviceGroup=/Application
```

after the split it should look like this

```
|RECEIVE|Low| 
 eventId=139569 
 msg=W4N Alert :: Critical : Interface Utilization for GigabitEthernet0/1 90.0 % 
 in=2442 
 out=0 
 categorySignificance=/Normal 
 categoryBehavior=/Communicate/Query 
 categoryDeviceGroup=/Application
```

the condition is identify the space before `key=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split using this regex `(?=\s\w+=)`

```
String str = "|RECEIVE|Low| ... p=/Application";
String[] spl = str.split("(?=\\s\\w+=)");
```

**Outputs**

```
|RECEIVE|Low|
 eventId=139569
 msg=W4N Alert :: Critical : Interface Utilization for GigabitEthernet0/1 90.0 %
 in=2442
 out=0
 categorySignificance=/Normal
 categoryBehavior=/Communicate/Query
 categoryDeviceGroup=/Application
```

---

- #### ideone demo
- #### regex demo

Comment: What's the inner parentheses for?

Comment: thank you @shmosel i was testing for that i don't make attention thank you very much i edit it